# Using 'am I' for non question sentence

Tags: grammar

Is there any exception where 'am I' is used but not for question? Thank you

Comment: *["Yoda am I"](http://www.renniesgallery.co.uk/product/yoda-craig-davison/), said Yoda.*  Or for something that was actually normal at the time, Hamlet's [*"Oh, what a rogue and peasant slave am I!"*](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/hamlet/page_128.html). I think this question is a bit too basic/open-ended.

Comment: 'All at once I am / several stories high' wouldn't have lasted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

A: "I am not a jerk!"

B: "Nor **am I**."

Comment: You're right, i didn't think of this. Do you have any other example? And thank you for helping

Comment: There are the similar constructions using _neither_ and _so_; there are also inversions after negative adverbials and the like (_Rarely am I at a loss for words_; _Not for nothing am I known as the Scourge of the West_ ...).

Comment: Thank you for this, really helpful! My colleagues and I have been going around in circles for 1 hour now trying to find examples or make sense of this